# How can I select a range of a Matlab timeseries object?

Tags: matlab, time-series, data-extraction

I have a Matlab `timeseries` object with content

`Time: [1000x1 double]
Data: [1000x1 double]`.

How can I select the first *n* (f.e. 300) points of the `timeseries`? I would like to find a function that allows me to write `timeseries2=timeseries1(1:300)`, rather than

`timeseries2.Data=timeseries1.Data(1:300)
timeseries2.time=timeseries1.time(1:300)`

I have looked in the Matlab help function, but could not find it yet.

Comment: Which toolbox's `timeseries` are you using? There's a plethora of them according to the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried using basic indexing? `yourObject.Data(1:300)`

Comment: @Adriaan - The [timeseries class](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries-class.html), resulting from a [to workspace](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html?refresh=true) sink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ts2=ts.getsamples(1:300)
```

[documented here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.getdatasamples.html)